# Splitting Cells - Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, vba

What's wrong with my code?

I want to extract the paint code from a part number. The part number is in column "H", and I want the paint code in column "I". For example: for `GP231-5003-XCBK` I want `XCBK` to appear in column "I".

Here is the code so far:

```
Dim K As Long
Dim LR As Long
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xIUp).Row

For K=2 to LR
     Cells(K,9).Value = Right(Cells(K,8).Value, Len(Cells(K,8))-InStr(1, Cells(K,8).Value, "-"))
Next K

End sub
```

The error occurs at `LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xIUp).Row`

Comment: it is `xlUp` not `xIUp`.  Lowercase `L` not upper case `I`

Comment: You need `Option Explicit` at the top of the module.

Comment: And I would use: `Cells(K,9).Value = Split(Cells(K,8).Value,"-")(uBound(Split(Cells(K,8).Value,"-")))`

Comment: Furthermore I'd recommend to fully qualify your range references, as without further qualification VBA addresses any currently active sheet which need not be the actually wanted reference.

Comment: I've made the following from the comments, but I still have the same error. My code now: `Dim K As Long
  Dim LR As Long
  LR = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Aluminum Futures").Cells(Rows.Count, K).End(xlUp).Row

  For K = 2 To LR
   ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Aluminum Futures").Cells(K, 9).Value = Split(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Aluminum Futures").Cells(K, 8).Value, "-")(UBound(Split(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Aluminum Futures").Cells(K, 8).Value, "-")))
  Next K`

Comment: Please update your question with your new code. As you can see, posting a bunch of code in comments just leaves a mess.

Comment: `.Cells(Rows.Count, K).End(xlUp).Row ` the K should be 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comments:

1. it should be `xlup` not `xIUp`.  that is a lowercase `L`
2. Use Split instead of trying to parse with Right and Len.
3. Make sure you use the worksheet parent to ranges.

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Aluminum Futures")
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim K As Long
    For K = 2 To LR
        Dim str() As String
        str = Split(.Cells(K, 8), "-")
         .Cells(K, 9).Value = str(UBound(str))
    Next K
End With
```

Comment: @Bert328 ... 3.1. note the "."-prefixes within the `With`..`End With` block, systematically even before `.Rows.Count`)